# Generic Inquiry time format

Tags: acumatica

In a Generic Inquiry, I'm trying to format the time part of a DateTime field in the results.  I don't currently see any way to do this without parsing the date as a string, but I must be missing something. Using the Format() function, running the query tells me "The method or operation is not implemented". Using the Minute() function gets the minutes part, but using the Hour() function says "Unsupported formula operator Hour".

Comment: What is the desired format you are trying to get in the result?

Comment: I tried to do this in 6.1 and never found a solution. GI's cannot use time format correctly. The only way I got this to work was to create an unbound field that would format a string field to display the time which seems clunky.

Comment: Casval, simply hour and minute format, 12-hour with AM/PM would be best, but just can't get the hour portion without parsing.

Comment: Thanks Brendan, that at least confirms my issue, and I may do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add CRCase table in your tables and don't join with any tables under Relations tab, and in result grid, under Schema field use CRCase.CreatedDateTime, with this you will get the result in DateTime format.
let me know if this is my wrong assumption to your question.

Comment: I saw this scenario mentioned elsewhere when searching for a solution, but I don't understand it. What does CRCase have to do with anything? Can it be any datetime field from any table?  Plus, I don't want the date portion, only the time, so I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Is there a better solution than this, or is this it? Feels like it's a bandaid instead of a solution.